# Crystal report flowing text around image

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to have this [layout](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/samplewu.jpg/) in crystal reports:

How to do this?

[image]

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340666/crystal-report-or-ssrs-flowing-text-around-image

Comment: Yes but they didnt answer how it is possible to wrap text around images.:-).i want to generate multile colums using dynamic text not using static text..Please reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the following data fetched from the database you can corretly obtined the output you want with out any repetition in column values :-).I think you put static data in the label field and set the muti column layout.right?

Answer (score 1):

For image layout, I have no knowledge.

**Multi Column layout:**

Multi-Column layout is available in Crystal Report. For multiple columns:

```
1. Go to the detail section. Resize it so that it takes the width of a
single column.
2. Add your fields of interest to the details section. Resize them so
that they only use the specified width only.
3. Go into your Section Expert. In the section "Details", turn on the
Format with Multiple Columns option.
4. A new tab "Layout" will now be visible. It allows additional
formating including gap between the columns etc.
```

This should do the multi-column layout.

Comment: Thanks alot.multiple colums is working properly .sir if u dont mind could u please tell me how to wrap text around images

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of the way to wrap text around image. You can think of overlay, but otherwise, I am not aware of any other way to implement this. You can post it to the Crystal Report official forum on SAP website.

Comment: Ok thanks you :-)..One more issue arising while i trying to export generated crystal reports to pdf .column data's are repeating in the generated pdf.

Comment: Not getting you exactly. Why don't you put the pdf (a page or so) in your post?

Comment: i have uploaded the pdf.its the exported pdf from crystal reports.